# How to find the adress of my modem

Tags: pppoe, dsl-modem

I tried every single default ip adress, even reversed. This modem is outside of my house so i need ladder to access it, something is goin wrong with the PPPoE connection and the error it's not in my OS. I tried Linux, Win10-8 and Win7 Professional then Ultimate, is either the modem was not found or it responded with an error. Sometime it fixes itself sometimes i don't have connection very long time. At least i need to find the control panel of the modem, how i can scan for internal lan adresses?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Post your the output of `ipconfig /all`, mask out your public ip address, if you are not behind a NAT.